# How To Get SqlConnection Instantiated?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am following a tutorial to make an ASP.NET web app and came to the part of establishing a connection to my SQL database item I added withing VisualStudio via Add>New Item command when right-clicking on my project name in Solution Explorer.

However, after putting the appropriate namespaces, VS is not recognizing the SQLConnection I'm trying to instantiate.

I keep getting the error: "the modifier 'new' is not valid for this item" among others.

I already tried removing the "@" symbol, already tried putting the path in a string, but now VS is not even recognizing a simple string instantiation!

Here is code version 1:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AdressBook
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename|DataDirectory\AdressBookDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
```

Here is code version 2:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace AdressBook
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page

        string datapath = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename|DataDirectory\AdressBookDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"

        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(datapath);
```

I expect there to be no red/green underlines and be able to connect to my database when a button is clicked. What is wrong?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: You are missing a semi colon at end of string datapath = "blah"

Comment: @Programnik Sorry, I copied wrong. I have the semicolon at the end of the path and it's still not instantiating.

Comment: @Vlam I wasn't, I was using the SQL Server Databse Item when adding a new item via Add>New Item.

Comment: Try `Server=.\SQLExpress;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|AdressBookDatabase.mdf;Database=yourdbname;
Trusted_Connection=Yes;` Note that there is an equal sign after `AttachDbFilename`. Add your own database name in there. Also AdressBookDatabase.mdf is correct spelling?

Comment: @Vlam Thanks, I tried it but still no good. The main issue isn't even the argument, it's that VS isn't recognizing my instantiation of SQLConnection even though I provided the System.Data.SqlClient namespace. And haha yeah I misspelled 'Address' but I can correct that later. Also, where would I get the info to fill in "yourdbname"?

Comment: May be a typo, but the code (both version) is missing the opening brace (`{`) for the Page class.

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn It was a code snippet, there is a brace: https://i.imgur.com/LmDqrJi.png

Comment: @Joel Coehoorn Sorry, you were correct and I was partially correct. I did need the curly brace but I already had it in my code. I was just blindingly putting my code before the brace which made me believe I never had it in the first place. I found my error and it's resolved. Thank you.

And oh, more to your point I thought my fault lied within the code itself and not the brace format, which is why I only included that snippet. I'll know better next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this is a copy/paste error, but you're missing the curly brace at the start of the class:

```
namespace AdressBook
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {   //<---- opening curly brace required!
        string datapath = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename|DataDirectory\AdressBookDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
```

Comment: I wish I had reputation or else I could have posted images. I have the curly images, too lol. Maybe I can try, here are the links: https://i.imgur.com/ejNBJeJ.png https://i.imgur.com/zAO5MRF.png

Comment: YOU WERE RIGHT I WAS SO BLIND. It took Vlam's answer for me to see it but you were the one to actually to tell me verbatim. It's working now thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following and it works for my VS2017.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\v11.0;Integrated Security=true;AttachDbFileName=C:\\Users\\MySelf\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2017\\Projects\\TestSQL\\TestSQL\\App_Data\\Database.mdf;");
    }
}
```

Comment: That's great to see. I dunno what's wrong with mine. I can't even set up a simple string without getting red syntax error (ex. string dog = "woof";)

Comment: Sounds like you didn't escape some characters or are missing some semi-colons somewhere above that line.

Comment: Yes, I was putting my code between the space of the header and curly bracket and not between the curly brackets. I moved my code to the correct spot and it works now, thanks.